# How to include a manytomany field in a postgres full text search in django

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, django-queryset

I am trying to do a full text search in postgres using these models

````
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # Able to login
    practitioner = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # has access to a clinc
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # superuser
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # staff
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Modalities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                related_name='prof_user',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    mods = models.ManyToManyField(Modalities)
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    clinics = models.ManyToManyField(Clinic)
    personnummer = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    consent = models.BooleanField()


class Clinic(models.Model):
    practitioner = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                        related_name='prac_user',
                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    lng = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, )
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=128, )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128, )```
````

So far I am able return search results with

```
def search(request):
    search_vector = SearchVector('practitioner__first_name', 'name',
                                 'description', 'street', 'city')
    results = Clinic.objects.annotate(search=search_vector).filter(
        search='Göteborg').values_list('name',
                                       'street',
                                       'city',
                                       'lat',
                                       'lng',
                                       'pk',
                                       flat=False)


    def list_of_results(results):        
        key_list = ['name', 'street', 'city', 'lat', 'lng', 'clinic_id']
        r_list = []
        object = []
        for p in results:
            r_list.append([p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]])        
        for array in r_list:
            object.append(dict(zip(key_list, array)))
        return object

    search_result = list_of_results(results)
```

I would also like to be able to include Profile.mods in search_vector to be able to return results for matching Modalities.

I have tried adding profile__mods like so;

```
def list_of_results(results):
        key_list = [
            'name', 'street', 'mods', 'city', 'lat', 'lng', 'clinic_id'
        ]
        r_list = []
        object = []
        for p in results:
            r_list.append([p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5], p[6]])
        for array in r_list:
            object.append(dict(zip(key_list, array)))
        return object
```

But I get the error "Cannot resolve keyword 'mods' into field. Choices are: city, description, id, lat, lng, name, phone, practitioner, practitioner_id, profile, street"

How am I able to include this in my search?

Comment: Are you not able to add `profile__mods__name` to the `SearchVector` or are you not able to return the values themselves in the list of results?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do with `list_of_results`. If instead of `values_list(...)` you'd use `values()` you'd get the result you want directly without having to use `list_of_results` function at all.

Comment: Note that the related mods are a query in itself, so you cannot include them in `values()` or `values_list`. You have to fetch them with a separate query, e.g. `Modalities.objects.filter(profile__clinics__in=results)`.

Comment: when I use values() I get the error; "Too many values to unpack".
Either way, for the moment list_of_results does wjhat I need, my real problem is in the search function and like you said, I may have to run another query. I'll give that a try, thanks

Comment: You get "too many values to unpack" if you try to put a m2m field in there (and you also get it for `values_list()`). But yes, you need to query separately for m2m fields (and loop through them separately).

Comment: Thanks,  I'm not sure where to add Modalities.objects.filter(profile__clinics__in=results)
I'm getting: Cannot use multi-field values as a filter value.

Comment: right, if `results` has `values_list` with multiple fields it won't work. Replace `results` with `qs` where `qs` is the Queryset without `values_list()`. Or with just `values('pk')`.

Comment: If you're not using a m2m to search in your question is not full-text related but is a queryset question.